# Errors while trying to install applications

Tags: apt, upgrade, software-installation, dpkg

Today I started having problems with installing applications, I spent half my day googling it and nothing I try works.

Here's the terminal output:
[Link to pastebin (it's really long)](http://pastebin.com/12MtagXd)

I get the same output when using

- `apt install -f`
- `apt dist-upgrade`
- `apt upgrade`
- `apt autoremove`

First I tried turning it off and on again - but that didn't fix it,
and now it's preventing me from installing anything.

Then I tried `apt remove --purge` on all the packages it listed at the end, all the commands I listed above, all with the same result.

It really bugs me, because I switched to `i3wm` and now I can't even install anything to customize it or expand functionality.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you post the output of `dpkg -l linux*` too

Comment: [Here it is](http://pastebin.com/vge25HMf)

Comment: Did you try to remove kernels manually?

Answer (score 1):

I tried removing the packages manually as suggested in the comments

- I removed from `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` every file that was mentioned at the end of the error log.

Now, I have managed to install a few  applications without any errors. So far it seems to be working fine, hopefully it won't happen again. Thanks for your help!

Edit: After I tried to boot again some time later, I get an error saying that a file from `/boot` is missing - I give up, I'll just reinstall ubuntu

Comment: Nice to hear that, just don't forget to check this answer as the correct one when you confirm every thing is fine.

Comment: I will, when the site lets me :) Thanks for your help with the problem (and the editing)